# useIonViewWillEnter has default value of state variable upon re-entry of page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5, ionic-react

I am not sure if this is expected behavior between Ionic React **4.8.0-rc.0** to **5.2.2**

**Scenario**

- I have multiple tab where Tab 1 has list of items from API call and Tab 2 has other stuffs.
- When I first run the app, Tab 1 will trigger API call to populate items
- I want to navigate between tabs but Tab 1 items should stay the same

**Finding**

What I found out is that `items1` always become `[]` when I come back to **Tab1** for Ionic React **5.2.2**. However, version **4.8.0-rc.0** does not have this strange behavior, meaning `items1` value is the same within `useIonViewWillEnter` after navigating away and back to **Tab1**

```
  useIonViewWillEnter(async () => {
    console.log(items1);
    if (items1.length < 4) {
      setItems1([1, 2, 3]);
    }
  });
```

**4.8.0-rc.0**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-tabs-lj2ekk

**5.2.2**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-tabs-tvtv3c

You can test by clicking on **Add by 1** button to see the list increasing. Then navigate away and back. In **5.2.2**, the list will be back to `[1, 2, 3]` again.

So my question is: Is this a bug? If not, is the behavior now different and how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it

```
useIonViewWillEnter(async () => {
    console.log(items1);
    if (items1.length < 4) {
      setItems1([1, 2, 3]);
    }
  },[items1]);
```